# High Fluctuations in Validation Curve

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition, overfitting

Below I attach an image of accuracy curves. I got a lot of suggestions regarding some improvement in below curves. Following are my experiments in order to make the curve stable-->

1. I used lr = 4.44e-5
2. Weight decay = 3e-6
3. Used BatchNorm and Dropouts in architecture

I feel that weight updates are very sensitive to validation data, but not very sensitive to train data. I would appreciate any suggestions for making validation curve stable (currently just concerned with stability, not with overfitting or under-fitting)

My model is 1.3 M parameters large. Total dataset = 13,000 hyper-spectral images of wheat seads.
Test_size = 20%
Train size = 55%
Validation size = 25%

Here is my model architecture :

```
class HSIModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self , config, n_res_blocks = 12):
    super(HSIModel, self).__init__()
    self.config = config
    self.in_channels = self.config['in_channels']
    self.n_res_blocks = n_res_blocks
    self.squeeze_channels = 512
    self.model = self.get_model()
    self.layer_lr = [{'params' : self.base_model.parameters()},{'params': self.head.parameters(), 'lr': self.config['lr'] * 1}]


  def get_model(self):
    self.head = nn.Sequential(
                  nn.Flatten(1) ,
                  Dense(0.4, 512, 128), 
                  # Dense(0.15, 256, 128), 
    )
    li = [ResidualBlock(256) for i in range(self.n_res_blocks)]
    self.base_model = nn.Sequential(
        # BandAttentionBlock(self.in_channels), 
        SqueezeBlock(self.in_channels, 100),
        SqueezeBlock(100, 512),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.2) ,
        XceptionBlock(512, 256), 
        XceptionBlock(256, 256), 
        nn.Dropout(p=0.2) ,
        # XceptionBlock(256, 128),
        nn.Sequential(*li), 
        # XceptionBlock(128, 256), 
        # SeparableConvBlock(128, 256), 

        SeparableConvBlock(256,512), 
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = (3,3) ,stride = (2,2)) , 
        nn.Dropout(p=0.15) ,
        nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1,1)) ,
    )
    return nn.Sequential(
                  self.base_model,
                  self.head, 
                  Dense(0, 128, self.config['num_classes']),
                        )

  def forward(self, x):

    return self.model(x)
```

Below I also attach the code file where modules used in above architecture are written. Please also comment on architecture.

Pls help out, if you need any other information, pls mention[image]

The modules used in above model have their usual architecture.

Comment: what about the loss

Comment: Similar behaviour

Comment: Hi @SarvagyaPorwal and welcome to AI Stack Exchange! If possible, please outline a specific question for this post. It may help you get answers more quickly.